# Add a new dict to a existing dictionary as a value to the key

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    "apples":"21",
    "vegetables":"30",
    "sesame":"45",
    "papaya":"18",
}
```

I want to generate a new one that will look like this:

```
my_dict = {
    "apples" : {"apples":"21"},
    "vegetables" : {"vegetables":"30"},
    "sesame" : {"sesame":"45"},
    "papaya" : {"papaya":"18"},
}
```

I wrote a code like this ....

```
my_dict = {
    "apples":"21",
    "vegetables":"30",
    "sesame":"45",
    "papaya":"18",
}

new_dict={}
new_value_for_dict={}

for key in my_dict:
    new_value_for_dict[key]= my_dict[key]
    new_dict[key]= new_value_for_dict
    # need to clear the last key,value of the "new_value_for_dict"

print(new_dict)
```

And the output comes as this:

```
{'vegitables':{'vegitables': '30', 'saseme': '45', 
               'apples': '21','papaya': '18'},
 'saseme':{'vegitables': '30', 'saseme': '45', 
           'apples': '21', 'papaya': '18'}, 
 'apples': {'vegitables': '30', 'saseme': '45', 
            'apples': '21', 'papaya': '18'}, 
 'papaya': {'vegitables': '30', 'saseme': '45', 
            'apples': '21', 'papaya': '18'}
}
```

But is not how I expected. How do eliminate the repetition ?
How do I get it corrected ?

Comment: You are re-using the same dictionary over and over. Create a copy if you don't want to share it, or better yet, **create a new dictionary in the loop**.

Comment: Simply move `new_value_for_dict={}` under the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply create a new dict with a comprehension:

```
>>> {k:{k:v} for k,v in my_dict.items()}
{'sesame': {'sesame': '45'}, 'vegetables': {'vegetables': '30'}, 'papaya': {'papaya': '18'}, 'apples': {'apples': '21'}}
```

I don't see any reason to do so, though. You don't get more information but it becomes harder to iterate over the dict values or retrieve information.

As mentioned by @AshwiniChaudhary in the comments, you could simply move `new_value_for_dict={}` inside the loop in order to recreate a new inner-dict at each iteration:

```
my_dict = {
    "apples":"21",
    "vegetables":"30",
    "sesame":"45",
    "papaya":"18",
}

new_dict={}

for key in my_dict:
    new_value_for_dict={}
    new_value_for_dict[key]= my_dict[key]
    new_dict[key]= new_value_for_dict

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion !

Answer (score 2):

almost there

```
for key in my_dict:
...     my_dict[key]={key:my_dict.get(key)}
```